# Formatting string to display as list using php

Tags: php, html, string, list, format

I have the contents of a `textarea` being stored in a PHP string after it is submitted by the user. I am hoping to be able to tweak the formatting of the contents of that string, such that it will be displayable as a list when it is echoed. In other words, I would need to insert `UL` and `/UL` at the beginning and end, respectively, and LI and `/LI` and the beginning and end of each line.

Before I mess with my code, I was wondering if anyone knows if this is this even possible? Are carriage returns sent via `textarea` submit? Any help/comments would be much appreciated.

**[EDIT]**

I have defined some variables to give myself all the necessary HTML stuff. The 'repertoire' variable is the original string containing text sent from user input.

```
$repertoire = ($_POST['repertoire']); 

$list_start = '<UL>';
$list_end = '</UL>';
$list_end = '</UL>';
$list_start_line = '<LI>'; 
$list_end_line = '</LI>';
```

The following is an example of what would be submitted by the user, and therefore, what would constitute the original `$repertoire` string:

> Luciano Berio - Circles
>
> Mike Svoboda - Piangero la sorte mia
>
> Nicholas von Ritter-Zahony - New Piece
>
> Stefano Gervasoni - Due Poesie Francesi di Rilke

So we would at least need the following:

```
$repertoire_formatted = substr_replace($list_start, $repertoire, $list_end);
```

...but I don't know how to substitute `<LI>` for line breaks; also, I cannot know in advance the length of the string or of each line.

Comment: yes, that is possible, do mess with your code and show us what you've tried

Comment: hey, show your string its possible.

Comment: This is what will be submitted from the textarea. I was hoping that it might be possible to format this without converting it to an array (for complicated reasons).

Comment: Please edit question and add info to post instead of leaving comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to selecting every line and wrap it in `<li></li>`

```
$html = preg_replace("/([^\n]+)/", "<li>$1</li>", $repertoire);
$html = "<ul>\n$html</ul>";
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/sBqeE)

Comment: That is a very elegant solution!